# JSF dataTable optimized

Tags: jsf, optimization, datatable, grid

I´m using a dataTable and its elements get generated from diferent sources: xml files, database records and even cheking file names from specific paths in the system... the problem is when the system query the xml and the filenames data because it get all that info when the grid displays for the first time and it don´t even display that info because is more than a thousend rows and the grid only shows the first ten rows, so what should I use or which method of the dataTable I need to overwrite to only query for the elements ten by ten as the user navigates thrue the content of the grid?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for a lazy loading datatable model

Primefaces has it : [DataTable - Lazy Loading](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableLazy.jsf)

> DataTable has built-in support to deal with huge datasets. In order to enable lazy loading, a LazyDataModel needs to be implemented to query the datasource when pagination, sorting, filtering or live scrolling happens. This example demonstrates uses an in-memory list to mimic a real datasource like a database.